# Show family $F$ is normal on $H$ if and only if family $\{f \circ g : f\in F\}$ is normal in $G$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g$ be a non-constant analytic function on region $G$ in $C$ and let $F$ be a family of meromorphic functions on $H=g(G)$. Show that the family $F$ is normal on $H$ if and only if the family $\{f\circ g:f\in F\}$ is normal on $G$.

I don't have idea on how to go about it. I tried to use Arzela-Ascoli theorem but the problem statement  does not relate to the theorem's premise. I know that a family $F$ is normal if every sequence in $F$ has a subsequence which converges to a function $f\in H(G)$. Also, that a family $F$ in $H(G)$ is normal if and only if $F$ is locally bounded as per Montel's Theorem.
Also, there is a theorem that says a family $F\subset M(G)$ is normal in $C(G,C_{\infty})$ if and only if $\mu (F)=\{\mu (f):f\in F\}$ is locally bounded. However, none of these statements relate to the problem statement. Please provide help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F$ is normal iff, given a sequence $f_n\subset F$, there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ which is uniformly convergent on compact subsets of $g(G)$ and similarly for $F\circ g:=\{f\circ g:f\in F\}$.

Suppose that $F$ is normal and let $f_n\circ g$ be a sequence in $F\circ g$.  There exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ uniformly convergent on compact subsets of $g(G)$, and it is easy to see that $f_{n_k}\circ g$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $G$, thus $F\circ g$ is normal.
Now, suppose $F\circ g$ is normal. Let $f_n\subset F$ be a sequence of functions and let $\{K_i\}$ be an [exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets) of $G$. Since $g$ is nonconstant and holomorphic (thus continuous and open), $\{g(K_i)\}$ is an exhaustion of $g(G)$. Since $F\circ g$ is normal, there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}\circ g$ of $f_n\circ g$ uniformly convergent on $\{K_i\}$, which implies that $f_{n_k}$ is uniformly convergent on $\{g(K_i)\}$. Being an exhaustion, $f_{n_k}$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $g(G)$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks Caffeine! The converse argument is clever.